# Running Haiku r3alpha1 with VirtualBox

Tags: macos, osx-lion, virtualbox, haiku

I am trying to run Haiku r3alpha1 vmdk using Virtual Box (4.1.14 r77440) on Mac OS X 10.7.3. When I start the VM all I see is a row of icons and there is no activity on the OS. Does anyone have any idea how I can make it work?

Here is my settings:

General
Name:

Haiku_r1alpha3
OS Type:

Other/Unknown

System
Base Memory:

512 MB
Processor(s):

1
Execution Cap:

100%
Boot Order:

Hard Disk, CD/DVD-ROM
VT-x/AMD-V:

Enabled
Nested Paging:

Enabled

Display
Video Memory:

64 MB
3D Acceleration:

Enabled
2D Video Acceleration:

Disabled
Remote Desktop Server:

Disabled

Storage
IDE Controller

IDE Primary Master:

haiku-r1alpha3.vmdk (Normal, 689.06 MB)
  IDE Primary Slave:

blank-bfs-2048mb.vmdk (Normal, 2.00 GB)
  IDE Secondary Master (CD/DVD):

Empty

Audio
Host Driver:

CoreAudio
Controller:

ICH AC97

Network
Adapter 1:

PCnet-FAST III (NAT)

Serial Ports
Disabled

USB
Device Filters:

0 (0 active)

Shared Folders
None

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Comment: I actually gave up on it quite a while ago.

Answer (score 1):

Enable serial port, or use a nightly image from http://haiku-files.org/haiku/development